# java ssh library that supports keys generated by putty

Tags: java, ssh, putty

i want a java application to establish a remote connection using ssh.

i came across the libraries jsch and ganymed, which seem pretty good, but unfortunately don't support private keys generated by puttygen. i have read that you can also generate non-proprietary keys using puttygen, generating new keys or converting the old keys is no option in this case.

so... does anyone know any ssh library for java that supports those keys?

thanks a million!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to convert the keys to OpenSSH format: [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-used)

Comment: Right. This is not a JSCH problem, this is Putty problem :-)

Comment: thanks! even though i hoped there would be another solution :(

Answer (score 0):

For those returning to this thread ... recent versions of JSch now support PuTTY .ppk files.  They can be loaded with `JSch.addIdentity()` in the normal way.

Just be aware if the PPK is password protected you will likely need to add the JCE unlimited strength jars to the JRE to support the aes256-cbc cipher: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072135/1794485