# teamcity aes256-cbc error when retrieving git repository

Tags: git, aes, teamcity, jsch

I've just installed Teamcity 8.0.3 on a fresh Windows Server 2012 machine. Installation was successful, and I'm trying to configure an agent in order to fetch a project stored in a git server.
This server uses a ssh key. I've added it to my agent, but when it tries to retrieve the project this error appears.

```
Failed for the root 'rtogit' #1: List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.
```

I've seen, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989883/the-cipher-aes256-cbc-is-required-but-it-is-not-available) that I must change my policy, but I'm not a java expert and I don't know what I must do.

Can someone help me please?

Edit: I forgot to say that I've also installed GitExtensions 2.46 complete.

Comment: I also have this issue. Replacing the policy files in <TeamCity>\jre\lib\security means that the Teamcity Service fails to start up - so that doesn't work.

Comment: I just installed 8.05 to replace 8.03 and now I have this issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had this problem and found out my private key file was in the wrong format.  I'm not sure if you used PuTTYgen to generate the key but if so try "Export OpenSSH key" from the Conversions menu and use that file instead.

Answer (score 2):

In the `<TeamCity>\jre\release` file check for the `'JAVA_VERSION'` and download the corresponding jce version.
ensure that both the 'teamcity build agent' and 'teamcity server' services are stopped. replace the files and restart the service.

If teamcity has `JAVA_VERSION=1.7.0`, then download `JCEPolicyJDK7` version.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but now I have another error _Test connection failed in WAO :: WAOBuild. List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel_ ?

Comment: also make sure to restart TeamCity in Services