# Team City The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available

Tags: git, teamcity

I have installed team city from scratch but after setup the Version Control Settings to git with private key authentication method, I getting next error

> Failed to collect changes, error: List remote refs failed:
>   com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required,
>   but it is not available.

how it is possible to fix ? My source codes can't be downloaded..

thanks

Comment: I have no idea really, but my usual mistake when it comes to installed things and configuration in relation to TeamCity is that I install things as admin or similar, and run TeamCity as a different user. Have you tried logging in on the server with the teamcity service user and testing git then? It may be just a folder configuration that is missing.

Comment: I have founded the answer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html I need to use this files for resolve security problem.

Comment: A more detailed solution is explained in this question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989883/the-cipher-aes256-cbc-is-required-but-it-is-not-available][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989883/the-cipher-aes256-cbc-is-required-but-it-is-not-available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have founded the answer oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/… I need to use this files for resolve security problem