# The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available in java

Tags: java, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to establish SSH connection in java. I have openSSH private kek.ppk file and it has **Encryption: aes256-cbc** . When i try to load it in java, it throw **com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.**

I have searched this error with internet and find solution that we should convert that key file using **putty key gen**.

But i want to use **Encryption: aes256-cbc** to establish SSH in java.

For information :- I used windows 10 PRO OS.

Kindly help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072135/1611055?

Comment: I have tried it. Downloaded and copied the jar in JRE1.7/.../security/ path. But the issue not resolved, still the same. I using Eclipse and added java preference to java7. But no luck.

Comment: No duplicate key. Key working fine.

Comment: You say you _"copied the jar"_, which indicates you copied **one** jar, but the unlimited strength policy files consists of **two** jar files, and you need to make sure that they are copied into the lib/security folder of the JRE that is actually executing the code (and make sure they overwrite the existing files, my experience is that copying them through explorer sometimes doesn't actually overwrite them).

Comment: Yes  Mark Rotteveel, I copied both jars and overwrite existing jars in lib/security folder of the JRE. But still i got same error **com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.**