# How to ssh connect through Python Paramiko with ppk public key

Tags: python, ssh, putty, paramiko, public-key

I'm using [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to connect through SSH to a server.

Basic authentication works well, but I can't understand how to connect with public key.

When I connect with PuTTY, the server tell me this:

```
Using username "root".
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key@ddddd.com"
Passphrase for key "rsa-key@ddddd.com": [i've inserted the passphrase here]
Last login: Mon Dec  5 09:25:18 2011 from ...
```

I connect to it with this ppk file:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: rsa-key@dddd.com
Public-Lines: 4
[4 lines key]
Private-Lines: 8
[8 lines key]
Private-MAC: [hash]
```

With basic auth the error I get (from the log) is:

```
DEB [20111205-09:48:44.328] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
DEB [20111205-09:48:44.927] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication type (password) not permitted.
DEB [20111205-09:48:44.927] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Allowed methods: ['publickey', 'gssapi-with-mic']
```

I've tried to include that ppk file and set to `auth_public_key`, but didn't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: paramiko uses openssh format keys. Since the key is encrypted, you also need to decrypt the key first. Using an ssh-agent will make things much easier, and paramiko can check for agent keys automatically.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Ok @Adam and @Kimvais were right, Paramiko cannot parse .ppk files.

So the way to go (thanks to @JimB too) is to convert .ppk file to OpenSSH private key format; this can be achieved using [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use).

Then it's very simple getting connected with it:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('<hostname>', username='<username>', password='<password>', key_filename='<path/to/openssh-private-key-file>')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy`, unless you do not care about security. You are losing a protection against MITM attacks this way.   
For a correct solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883.

Comment: If you use key_filename to fetch the SSH key, you do not need a pw. That is what SSH keys are for. Or it is likely the password just for the key itself.

Answer (score 27):

For me I doing this:

```
import paramiko
hostname = 'my hostname or IP' 
myuser   = 'the user to ssh connect'
mySSHK   = '/path/to/sshkey.pub'
sshcon   = paramiko.SSHClient()  # will create the object
sshcon.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) # no known_hosts error
sshcon.connect(hostname, username=myuser, key_filename=mySSHK) # no passwd needed
```

works for me pretty ok

Comment: This is not public key, it's private key.

Comment: Indeed, the "key_filename" field is expecting private key.

With an OpenSSH public key the program issues this exception:

paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid OPENSSH private key file

Comment: connect like this if you have passphrase for RSA key pair 
ssh.connect('<your ip>', port=22, username='<username>',password='<passphrase for the RSA key>', key_filename='<full path of the private key>')

Comment: my key is file extenstion is ppk. am I need to change this ? ppk to pub ?

Answer (score 9):

To create a valid DSA format private key supported by Paramiko in Puttygen.

Click on Conversions then Export OpenSSH Key

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@VonC's answer to (deleted) duplicate question:

> If, as commented, Paraminko does not support PPK key, the official solution, as seen here, would be to use [PuTTYgen](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html).
>
> But you can also use the [Python library CkSshKey](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/pythonCkSshKeyRef.html) to make that same conversion directly in your program.
>
> See "[Convert PuTTY Private Key (ppk) to OpenSSH (pem)](https://www.example-code.com/python/ssh_ppk_to_pem.asp)"
>
> ```py
> import sys
> import chilkat
>
> key = chilkat.CkSshKey()
>
> #  Load an unencrypted or encrypted PuTTY private key.
>
> #  If  your PuTTY private key is encrypted, set the Password
> #  property before calling FromPuttyPrivateKey.
> #  If your PuTTY private key is not encrypted, it makes no diffference
> #  if Password is set or not set.
> key.put_Password("secret")
>
> #  First load the .ppk file into a string:
>
> keyStr = key.loadText("putty_private_key.ppk")
>
> #  Import into the SSH key object:
> success = key.FromPuttyPrivateKey(keyStr)
> if (success != True):
>     print(key.lastErrorText())
>     sys.exit()
>
> #  Convert to an encrypted or unencrypted OpenSSH key.
>
> #  First demonstrate converting to an unencrypted OpenSSH key
>
> bEncrypt = False
> unencryptedKeyStr = key.toOpenSshPrivateKey(bEncrypt)
> success = key.SaveText(unencryptedKeyStr,"unencrypted_openssh.pem")
> if (success != True):
>     print(key.lastErrorText())
>     sys.exit()
> ```