# Port forwarding with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to do some port forwarding from a python app using Paramiko.  I can set up the SSH connection just fine, but I'm a bit stumped as to how to use `paramiko.Transport`.  I've already found [this file](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/pkg/trunk/paramiko/demos/forward.py?rev=30), but I can't work out what's going on in it.  From looking at the [`paramiko.Transport` docs](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html), it seems that a single line using the `open_channel` function, but I can't work out how to implement that.  I'm trying to replicate a simple `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 21):

Please find some code using `paramiko-1.7.7.1`, `pycrypto-2.6` and the [forward.py script](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/forward.py) from which I did remove code from the line 115 to the end (to avoid options parsing).

```
import paramiko, sys
from forward import forward_tunnel

remote_host = "target_host"
remote_port = 8000
local_port  = 8000
ssh_host    = "my_ssh_host"
ssh_port    = 22

user     = "login"
password = "s3cr3t"

transport = paramiko.Transport((ssh_host, ssh_port))

# Command for paramiko-1.7.7.1
transport.connect(hostkey  = None,
                  username = user,
                  password = password,
                  pkey     = None)

try:
    forward_tunnel(local_port, remote_host, remote_port, transport)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Port forwarding stopped.'
    sys.exit(0)
```

I've tested it successfully from a Windows station, using a ssh server under Red Hat and pointing to a 3rd server. (I'm using `Python 2.7.2`)

Hope it helps,

Comment: The `hostkey=None` is insecure (and the very point of SSH tunneling is security, right?). Make sure you provide the actual host key, otherwise you are vulnerable to [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Or instead of low-level `Transport`, use high-level `SSHClient` with its built-in host key verification against `known_hosts` file (or other). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883

Answer (score 9):

You can use https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel

```
pip install sshtunnel
```

Code example:

```
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open(
    (ssh_host, ssh_port),
    ssh_host_key=None,
    ssh_username=ssh_user,
    ssh_password=ssh_password,
    ssh_private_key=None,
    remote_bind_address=(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT)) as server:

    def do_something(port):
        # Do something with port
        pass

    print("LOCAL PORT:", server.local_bind_port)

    do_something(server.local_bind_port)
```

Comment: looks like the indentation in code example is incorrect...?

Comment: This package does not do remote port forwarding, only local.