# ssh command with argument execution in python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I need to execute a ssh command with arguments in python. I have been able to execute the ssh command.But, I cannot figure out, how to pass the arguments.

The command:
ssh -L 22222:localhost:5434 sayan@155.97.73.252

Here is the code :

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient();
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy());
ssh.connect("155.97.73.252", username="sayan", password="#####");
```

Comment: This is just a command to do ssh port forwarding, which begs the question, why not just use ssh? [Port forwarding with paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12106387/642070) uses the [paramiko demo](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/pkg/trunk/paramiko/demos?rev=30) forward.py, if you want to stick with python.

Answer (score 3):

**paramiko Example**

```
 class RunCommand(cmd.Cmd):
        """ Simple shell to run a command on the host """



   prompt = 'ssh > '

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.hosts = []
        self.connections = []

    def do_add_host(self, args):
        """add_host 
        Add the host to the host list"""
        if args:
            self.hosts.append(args.split(','))
        else:
            print "usage: host "

    def do_connect(self, args):
        """Connect to all hosts in the hosts list"""
        for host in self.hosts:
            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(
                paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect(host[0], 
                username=host[1], 
                password=host[2])
            self.connections.append(client)

    def do_run(self, command):
        """run 
        Execute this command on all hosts in the list"""
        if command:
            for host, conn in zip(self.hosts, self.connections):
                stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command(command)
                stdin.close()
                for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
                    print 'host: %s: %s' % (host[0], line)
        else:
            print "usage: run "

    def do_close(self, args):
        for conn in self.connections:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RunCommand().cmdloop()
Example output:

ssh > add_host 127.0.0.1,jesse,lol
ssh > connect
ssh > run uptime
host: 127.0.0.1: 14:49  up 11 days,  4:27, 8 users,
load averages: 0.36 0.25 0.19
ssh > close
```

**fabric example**

```
from fabric import tasks

env.hosts = ['localhost', 'sunflower.heliotropic.us']
pattern = re.compile(r'up (\d+) days')

# No need to decorate this function with @task
def uptime():
    res = run('uptime')
    match = pattern.search(res)
    if match:
        days = int(match.group(1))
        env['uts'].append(days)

def main():
    env['uts'] = []
    tasks.execute(uptime)
    uts_list = env['uts']
    if not uts_list:
        return # Perhaps we should print a notice here?
    avg = sum(uts_list) / float(len(uts_list))
    print '-' * 80
    print 'Average uptime: %s days' % avg
    print '-' * 80

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How its work , 

Its provide a ssh interface in python, 
Once you connected to server you can run command(with or without params) as you are running in normal ssh terminal 
Just pass command with param to run method it will run it