# SSH with Putty to 'tunneled'

Tags: python, ssh, putty

I'm using Putty CLI on windows, with Python 2.7 
I have created tunnel from A >> B, since i cannot access B directly.
Tunnel:
    subprocess.Popen("putty -ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5001:10.25.248.50:22
    ubuntu@34.251.111.259 -i myppkfile.ppk"

This works!

Now i'm trying to access B with SSH in order to take tomcat down for instance
This is the code:
subprocess.Popen("putty -ssh  -p 5001 -i myppkfile.ppk ubuntu@127.0.0.1 -m path\file.txt (in file there is the command to take tomcat down for instance

This does not work!

Notes:
1.
Access directly to server via ssh works as well (server that is accessable and there is no need for tunnel)
    subprocess.Popen("putty vmadmin@172.31.80.10 -pw 1ssssss -m path\file.txt")

2.
Via linux i managed to access everything with no problem (using tunnel and -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no)

Any suggestion ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does invoking the second putty command work if you're doing it manually while the script is running (i.e. does it work manually, without warning etc., if the tunnel is already up?)

Comment: For automation, use Plink, not PuTTY. Though, there's native SSH implementation for Python, [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). See [Port forwarding with paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11294919/850848).

Comment: Trying plink...

Comment: Works like a magic!

Comment: Thank you very much