# Import forward_tunnel from forward error python

Tags: python, package, installation, portforwarding

Hello more intelligent individuals! Quick python question, I'm referencing [Port forwarding with paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294919/port-forwarding-with-paramiko) question and believed I was on the verge of success with the forward_tunnel function, however for some reason this doesn't come up in my forward package.

```
from forward import forward_tunnel
ImportError: cannot import name forward_tunnel
```

Not sure if this is an outdated function and if it is which one I should be using as supplement, ultimately trying to tunnel connect through remote ssh server but haven't had any luck with other methods thus far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foward.py` isn't the module to use. It's a demo  how to do **forwarding using paramiko**.
[demos/forward.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py)