# Tunneling not working using paramiko My machine > RDP to VM machine > network device via SSH

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Can you please assist. I am doing some channeling from my windows machine via python. I could not get into the remote desktop. I am using ssh, but I know this seems to be wrong. This is working to jumpbox which is linux based.

My machine(windows) > remote desktop(VM machine) > network device via ssh

CODE:

```
for device in devices:
device = device.rstrip()
#for jump in jumphost_devices:
print("Connecting to Device %s..." % (device),)
jhost = paramiko.SSHClient()
jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
jhost.connect('10.10.10.11', username=username, password=password, timeout=10)
vmtransport = jhost.get_transport()
dest_addr = (device, 22)
local_addr = ('10.10.10.11', 22)
vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
    #
host = paramiko.SSHClient()
host.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host.connect(device, username=username, password=password, sock=vmchannel, timeout=10)
remote_conn = host.invoke_shell()
#output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
```

ERROR:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PYTHON>python push2.py device.txt command.txt logs
Enter Username: EV24049584
Password:
Retype your password:
Connecting to Device 10.120.120.138...
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 622, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2215, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 622, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "push2.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "push2.py", line 125, in main
    ssh_access_command(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
  File "push2.py", line 89, in ssh_access_command
    jhost.connect('10.138.113.11', username=username, password=password, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 406, in connect
    t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 660, in start_client
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "C:\Users\xbsds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2215, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

thanks,

Comment: This looks wrong: `local_addr = ('10.10.10.11', 22)`. – For a simplicity, did you start trying with a [real forwarded port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11294919/850848) before going for `sock` solution?

Comment: I havent tried it yet. I'll try port forwarding if it will wok. Will keep you posted.