# Is it possible to send data from S3 to Raspberry pi using lambda function with S3 trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, raspberry-pi

I need lambda function to send the image from S3 to multiple Raspberry pi devices. Whenever there is new version of the picture uploaded in s3, it should trigger the function. and send the uploaded images to Rpi

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve it after setting Lambda on S3 trigger:

- Download the file using aws sdk in the /tmp/ folder. Lambda allows 512 MB storage.
- Use [paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499507/how-to-transfer-a-file-to-ssh-server-in-an-ssh-connection-made-by-paramiko) to transfer file/s to any number of Raspberry Pi servers.

OR

- [Create S3 presigned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60163406/9907481) URL/s in Lambda function for the specified S3 file/s.
- Run a [remote wget command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411997/9907481) on RaspBerry Pi's with presigned URL as input.

```
wget <presigned_url> -O /path/to/folder/
```

These solutions are based on python to give you an idea, yet you may find paramiko and remote script alternative libraries in other languages as well.