# Executing passwd command in Python Paramiko to change a password on a Linux server

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to write a Python 3 script to pragmatically ssh into a Linux server and change the password. I have put a script together using the Paramiko module.

I am running into issues when trying to run multiple shell commands. My script attempts to execute the commands but Paramiko times out after one shell command.

This is the script I am currently working on. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import paramiko

def change_pw():
    hostname = "IP" #IP Address of Linux Server
    username = "root" #username
    password = "oldpw!" #password for Linux Server

#NOTE - This variable is suppose to define 3 shell commands. I do not believe the script is sending these commands as listed because the password does not update.
    commands = [
        "passwd",
        "newpw!",
        "newpw!"
    ]

#NOTE - Attempted to utilize '\n' to execute multiple commands and failed
    # commands = [
    #     "passwd \n newpw! \n newpw!"
    # ]

    # initialize the SSH clientp0-
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    # add to known hosts
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
    except:
        print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
        exit()

    # execute the commands
    for command in commands:
        print("="*50, command, "="*50)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        print(stdout.read().decode())
        err = stderr.read().decode()
        if err:
            print(err)

change_pw()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have *three* commands. You have *one* command, the `passwd`, which takes two lines of input.

These two questions show how to provide an input to commands using Paramiko:

- [Pass input/variables to command/script over SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848)
- [Executing command using "su -l" in SSH using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51493317/850848)

So specifically for `passwd`, you need to use:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('passwd')
# answer the new password prompts
stdin.write('newpw\n')
stdin.write('newpw\n')
stdin.flush()
# wait for the command to complete a print the output
stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
print(stdout.read().decode())
```

For the purpose of the [`Channel.set_combine_stderr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.set_combine_stderr), see [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that I was trying to utilize 3 input commands to change the password for root. I only needed to call the passwd command and then pass two input variables for "Enter new PW" and "Confirm new PW"

```
import paramiko
import time

hostname = 'IP'
username = 'root'
password = 'oldpw'


commands = ['passwd']



# initialize the SSH clientp
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# add to known hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    exit()

# execute the commands
for command in commands:
    print("="*50, 'PW change executed', "="*50)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    stdin.write('newpw' '\n' 'newpw' '\n') #input varuables for "Enter new PW" and "re-enter new PW"
    stdin.flush()
    print(stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: What's the point of `for command in commands`, if you call only one command? The loop is not designed to ever work for multiple commands, as the code is tailored to `passwd` only. + Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way, it's a security flaw.