# Get command prompt via "sudo su -" then run command using Paramiko exec_command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Could you help me with following.
I need to login as user then `sudo su -` then run command ex. `parted -l` using Paramiko `exec_command`
when I run following code it hangs. Please let me know how I can check before gets to hanged.

```
with SSHClient() as client:
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('172.20.xxx.xx', port=22, username='xxx', password='xxxxxxx',timeout=15.0)
    transport = client.get_transport()
    session = transport.open_session()
    session.set_combine_stderr(True)
    session.get_pty()
    session.exec_command('sudo su -')
    time.sleep(5)
    stdin = session.makefile('wb', -1)
    stdout = session.makefile('rb', -1)
    stderr = session.makefile_stderr('rb', -1)
    stdin.write('xxxxxxx' + '\n')
    stdin.flush()
    session.exec_command('parted -l')
    time.sleep(5)
    stdin = session.makefile('wb', -1)
    stdout = session.makefile('rb', -1)
    stderr = session.makefile_stderr('rb', -1)
    stdin.flush()
    for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
        print 'LINE: %s' % (line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check result of the individual `parted` command? If you want to check results of individual commands, do not run shell (`su` in this case). Run the command only:

```
sudo su -c "parted -l"
```

See also [Executing command using "su -l" in SSH using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51493317/850848)

Then you can use `recv_exit_status()`:
[How can you get the SSH return code using Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3562403/850848)

---

If you want to keep your current approach for whatever reason, see:

- [Execute multiple dependent commands individually with Paramiko and find out when each command finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50962485/850848)
- [Combining interactive shell and recv_exit_status method using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57643574/850848)