# How to get each dependent command execution output using Paramiko exec_command

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko in order to execute a single or a multiple commands and get its output.

Since Paramiko doesn't allow executing multiple commands on the same channel session I'm concatenating each command from my command list and executing it in a single line, but the output can be a whole large output text depending on the commands so it's difficult to differentiate which output is for each command.

```
ssh.exec_command("pwd ls- l cd / ls -l")
```

I want to have something like:

```
command_output = [('pwd','output_for_pwd'),('ls -l','output_for_ls'), ... ]
```

to work easier with every command output.

Is there a way to do it without changing the Paramiko library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is (as @Barmar already suggested) to insert unique separator between individual commands. Like:

```bash
pwd && echo "end-of-pwd" && cd /foo && echo "end-of-cd" && ls -l && echo "end-of-ls"
```

And then look for the unique string in the output.

---

Though imo, it is much better to simply separate the commands into individual `exec_command` calls. Though I do not really think that you need to execute multiple commands in a row often. Usually you only need something like, `cd` or `set`, and these commands do not really output anything.

Like:

1. `pwd`
2. `ls -la /foo` (or `cd /foo && ls -la`)

---

For a similar questions, see:

- [Execute multiple dependent commands individually with Paramiko and find out when each command finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50962485/850848)  (for "shell" channel)
- [Combining interactive shell and recv_exit_status method using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57643574/850848)

Comment: I tried that approach but with ampersands instead pipes thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this for sending commands in ssh and telnet, you can capture the output with each command and try.

```
cmd = ['pwd', 'ls - lrt', 'exit']
cmd_output =[]
for cmd in cmd:
    tn.write(cmd)
    tn.write("\r\n")
    out = tn.read_until('#')
    cmd_output.append((cmd,out))
    print out
```

Comment: I don't think it's an interactive session, so there's no prompt.