# Python Paramiko vs Putty

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, paramiko

i would like to ask a very simple question, i have a script which will connect to oracle database for some activities

If i executed the scriptfrom PUTTY, it able to connect to database BUT if i execute the script in Python using paramiko client, it cant connect to database.

I guess it's environment issue but i'm not quite sure. Please give your opinion.

Below is the exact command i use in putty.

```
cd tes1/test2/runtime/; ./test.init.start
```

And this is what I try in Python with Paramiko:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('<Hostname>', username='<username>', password='<password>')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cd tes1/test2/runtime/; ./test.init.start')
```

UPDATE:

```
ERROR MESSAGE=
?WCSERV-F-Error during connect to data base
?SQ-F-connect to database failed 
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

LATEST UPDATE:
Hi i solved this and i figured this might help others, so the reason was the environment path messed up as im using paramiko, tried many ways but only 1 work which is running the script explicitly via login shell for example : `bash --login -c "ls"`, goodluck!

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: Already, just added

Comment: To clarify, is this an issue with the actual connection with the database (line 3 trace) or to do with running the script? If it's the latter, it seems like an Oracle question.

Comment: I don't think it's oracle issue because it works well if i executed the script in Putty, just when i executed using paramiko in python, i will get the error message

Comment: `ORA-12162` is an Oracle error code. I'm not too familiar with Oracle, but a Google search tells me you might need to set a `ORACLE_SID` environment variable. All in all, I don't know if there's enough information to answer the question.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49496127/11633985) might help.

Comment: Tried to include ORACLE_SID in the command but seems like no effect

Comment: hi guys, i've solved the issue and editted the question above on the the solution