# How to source environment file in python?

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to automate an application restarts with Python which is currently implemented with shell scripts. Before running the restart commands, we need to source a .sh environment file which is done in the shell script with
. ./opt/**/**/**.sh. I am using paramiko and exec_command to run the restart command which throws the error that libraries are missing. So I have tried several ways to source this environment file in the python program but have not been successful.

Things I have tried:

1. stdin1,stdout1,stderr1 = ssh_client1.exec_command(". ./opt/**/**/**.sh")
2. stdin1,stdout1,stderr1 = ssh_client1.exec_command("source /opt/**/**/**.sh")
3. subprocess.call("/opt/**/**/**.sh", shell=True)
4. os.system(". /opt/**/**/**.sh")
5. I picked the below from stack overflow if I remember correctly
   `enter code here`command = shlex.split("bash -c 'source /opt/**/**/**.sh'")
   `enter code here`proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
   `enter code here`for line in proc.stdout:
   `enter code here`(key, _, value) = line.partition("=")
   `enter code here`os.environ[key] = value
   `enter code here`proc.communicate()

I still get the same error missing libraries which I am supposed to get when I do not source the environment file when I run the application restart commands using exec_command("/opt/**/**/start")

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Prikryl: [Execute multiple commands in Paramiko so that commands are affected by their predecessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492621/execute-multiple-commands-in-paramiko-so-that-commands-are-affected-by-their-pre/49496127#49496127)

I love you man!! I am writing a py script to remote ssh with paramiko that sources a local environment file before running application restart commands. I was breaking my head over this for over 2 weeks, until I read this post. It works like a charm. Thank you!!

Solution: 
Each exec_command multiple times is executed in its own "shell". So the previous commands have no effect on an environment of the following commands.

Use && to combine the commands. In this way, the previous command, which in my case is the environment file, has an effect on the following command.

stdin3,stdout3,stderr3 = ssh_client1.exec_command(". /opt///env.sh && STOP")