# Set environment variable (PGPASSWORD) before executing a command (pg_dump) on Windows SSH server in Paramiko

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, ssh, paramiko

I want to create a backup of my postgres database via SSH connecting to a Windows Server 2019. I use the Paramiko Python library in order to do this, but unfortunately the sql-file does not contain any data (file size is 0 and files cannot not deleted as they are still opened in cmd). 
Thus, I suspect the execution of my command hasn't finished ...
This is my function:

```
def ssh_server(server, username, password, pg_pass, ps_user, database):

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect(hostname=server, username=username, password=password)

    stdin_2, stdout_2, stderr_2 = client.exec_command("SET PGPASSWORD=secret_pw")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(
        "pg_dump -U {} {} > kp_{}.sql\n".format(
            ps_user, database, ts_str), get_pty=True)

    client.close()
```

BTW: Executing the commands in PuTTY yields the desired output.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically this question:
[Execute multiple commands in Paramiko so that commands are affected by their predecessors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492621/850848).

The only difference, is that you are on Windows, where `set` includes even training spaces to the value of the variable. So make sure there are no spaces between the password and the `&&`:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=secret_pw&&pw_dump
```