# Paramiko close connection doesn't work

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm having trouble trying to close a Paramiko SFTP connection. Even though I call close the connection is still hanging, I check by running netstat (Windows):

```
netstat -an | find ":22"
```

and the python code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy() )
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
time.sleep(5)
ftp.close()
```

What is the proper way to close Paramiko SFTP connection that works?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to go about it

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect()

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

ftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

You need to close the ssh instance as well as the sftp.

Answer (score 3):

`SSHClient.open_sftp` opens a virtual SFTP channel within a SSH connection. You can have multiple channels in a single SSH connection. Hence closing a single channel, won't close whole SSH connection.

You need to call [`SSHClient.close`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.close) to close the physical SSH connection (it takes all channels down with it, if any are still open).

```
ssh.close()
```

---

Obligatory warning: Do not use `MissingHostKeyPolicy` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

For a correct (and secure) approach, see: [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).