# Paramiko ssh exec_command for IPv6 server from windows client

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

The following code is working fine to get output of command execution on remote server for IPv4 using `paramiko.SSHClient`. But the same code is not working for IPv6 server.

```
import paramiko
dssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
dssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
dssh.connect("IPv6_Address", username="root", password="orange")
stdin,stdout,stderr=dssh.exec_command("pwd")
print(stdout.read())
```

and then I tried to use socket connection for IPv6 like below

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((hostname, port))
t = paramiko.Transport(sock)
```

but `paramiko.Transport` has no `exec_command`.

Answer (score 1):

[`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) has `sock` parameter:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("IPv6_Address", port))
dssh.connect("IPv6_Address", username="root", password="orange", sock=sock)
```

---

*Side note: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` like that. You lose security by doing so.

See [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.