# Process started with PowerShell Start-Process using Python's Paramiko exec_command is not working although it is working fine from SSH terminal

Tags: python, powershell, ssh, paramiko, start-process

I want to execute a Python script as Administrator. I'm using the following command to do so:

```
powershell Start-Process python -ArgumentList "C:\Users\myuser\python_script.py","-param1", "param1","-param2","param2" -Verb "runAs"
```

This command works fine if I'm using traditional SSH using a terminal.
Target machine is Windows RS4 and I'm using the new native SSH server available since RS3.

My client's Python code is:

```
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=myhost, username=myuser, password='trio_012')
stdin, stdout, stderror = ssh_client.exec_command("powershell Start-Process python -ArgumentList \"C:\Users\myuser\python_script.py\",\"-param1\", \"param1\",\"-param2\",\"param2\" -Verb \"runAs\"")

print 'stdout:', stdout.readlines()
print 'stderror:', stderror.readlines()
```

The output I'm getting:

```
stdout: []
stderror: []
```

I don't see the script is running on the other side and it seems like nothing happens.
I don't know what is the problem cause I'm getting no output.

I'm using Paramiko 1.18.5 (I can't use the new v2, I'm having issues with `known_hosts` file and Windows when using `paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()` policy)

Comment: @MartinPrikry l I've mentioned I'm using the ssh server coming as part of Windows RS4 (you install it by demand in "apps and features").
I use paramiko frequently, most commands I've tried works, even other powershell commands. I didn't have success with commands that requesting to run as administrator.
I interested to know why this specific command works with ssh but not with paramiko.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I don't see it asking. There's a part in my python script that works only with admin privileges and it seems to work when executed using the terminal.
I also tired to disable UAC, but it's behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process, started with `Start-Process`, closes, when an SSH channel that started it is closed.

The "exec" channel (`exec_command`) closes immediately after the `powershell` process finishes, what is almost instantaneous. So I believe that your `python` process is actually started, but is taken down almost immediately.

It should help, if you add `-Wait` switch to `Start-Process`.

```
stdin, stdout, stderror =
    ssh_client.exec_command("powershell Start-Process python -ArgumentList \"C:\Users\myuser\python_script.py\",\"-param1\", \"param1\",\"-param2\",\"param2\" -Verb \"runAs\" -Wait")
```

---

It "works" from an SSH terminal, because the terminal (SSH "shell" channel) stays open after `powershell` process finishes. But if you close the terminal before the `python` process finishes, it would terminate it too.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).*