# Run a command (to backup a configuration) on multiple servers (routers) in Python

Tags: python, networking, ssh, paramiko, cisco

Is it possible to have a script iterate through each IP and backup running configuration on a local tftp server

```
import paramiko
import sys
import time


USER = "root"
PASS = "cisco"
HOST = ["10.10.10.10","11.11.11.11","12.12.12.12"]
i=0
while i <len(HOST)
def fn():
  client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
  #Add missing client key
  client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  #connect to switch
  client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
  print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST

 show run | redirect tftp://10.10.10.20/HOST.cfg 
print "Configuration has been backed up"for  %HOST
i+1
```

`show run | redirect tftp://10.10.10.20/HOST.cfg` --- can I use variable name as a text file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `for h in HOST` to iterate your `HOST` array;
- Use [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) to execute the command;
- Use [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) to format your messages and commands.

```
for h in HOST:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    #Add missing client key
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    #connect to switch
    client.connect(h, username = USER, password = PASS)
    print("SSH connection to {0} established".format(h))
    command = "show run | redirect tftp://10.10.10.20/{0}.cfg".format(h)
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print(line)
    client.close()
    print("Configuration has been backed up for {0}".format(h))
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` - You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848)*.