# SFTP connection failed socket.timeout?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am attempting to connect to one of our SFTP servers in order to automate a report. We pull a file from this server once a week and I am not able to get this connections to work. I am not finding any useful references to the below traceback error. Anyone have an idea of what could be causing this problem?

I get a socket.timeout error after 2 or 3 seconds of executing the code.

```
import paramiko


cli = paramiko.SSHClient()

cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
cli.connect(hostname='AHOST', port=21, username="USER", password="PASS")

stdin_, stdout_, stderr_ = cli.exec_command("ls -l ~")
print(stdout_.readlines())

cli.close()
```

Traceback:

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2138, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 367, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 576, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1966, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2143, in _check_banner
    "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2138, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 367, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 576, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user_name/PycharmProjects/PDD_Report/MAIN/MAIN.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli.connect(hostname='A40T', port=21, username="user_name", password="gate001")
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 397, in connect
    t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 587, in start_client
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1966, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Python 3.6.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2143, in _check_banner
    "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Comment: Check that: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/673  hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to FTP port 21.

SSH/SFTP uses port 22 (what is the default value of the `port` parameter, which you override).

---

Side note 1: Your question is about SFTP. Yet, instead of using [`SFTPClient`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html), you use `SSHClient` and execute *shell* commands – That has nothing to do with SFTP.

---

Side note 2: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` like this. You
lose security by doing so.
See [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).

Comment: Thanks Martin I will make some changes. I was following some basic examples on this library and the port 21 is what is set up in my FTP connections so I will double check everything.

Comment: All of what I tried using Paramiko failed. So I switched to the build in library `ftplib` and the connection works fine through that library. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: ftplib is FTP library. Your question is about SFTP. SFTP and FTP are two completely different protocols. So basically you have asked a wrong question.

Comment: Ya. My assumption was the connection type our main tool uses was SFTP by the name but I guess it does both and we were actually using FTP only.