# Dump JSON files directly into a remote SSH connection without storing them in local machine first

Tags: python, json, ssh, paramiko

I need to dump data in form a JSON file into a remote server using SSH connection, but I need to dump the data directly into the remote server without dumping it in my local machine first. I am using Paramiko for the SSH connection but I am open to other solutions.

I am extracting data from a database and converting this data into dictionaries data structures. Now I would like to dump these dictionaries in the form of a JSON file but I can not save the data in my local machine. I need to dump it directly into a server, which I connect via Python with Paramiko. I need to do everything at the same moment, extract the data from the database, convert into dictionaries, and dump it into the remote server as JSON files.

Here I add some dummy code with the basics of my needs.

```py
import paramiko

dicty = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('141.42.48.20', username='user', password='psw')

with open('dictionary.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dicty, outfile, default=myconverter)

ssh.close()
```

What I need is, instead of dumping the data into `outfile`, I would like to dump it into the ssh client.
I am open to another solution or framework. I just need a dictionary as a JSON going to the server directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the plain (local) `open` with [Paramiko `SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open):

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

with sftp.open('dictionary.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dicty, outfile, default=myconverter)
```

---

Obligatory warning:
Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` like this. You lose security by doing so.
See [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).