# How to access to a remote server using Paramiko with a public key-file

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access, paramiko

I need to connect to a remote server without the use of a password but using a public keyfile using the Python module Paramiko.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `key_filename` argument of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect):

```
import paramiko
 
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect("example.com", username="user", key_filename="mykeyfile")
```

Though you need *private* key file for that. You cannot authenticate with *public* key file.

---

You will also need to verify the host key:
[Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)