# "getaddrinfo failed" when connecting to SFTP server using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, python-3.7, paramiko

I am trying to connect to SFTP server but it returns error:

> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

I am using Python 3.7.3 and Paramiko version is 2.6.0

```
import paramiko

host_name = "sftp://81.149.151.143"
user_name = "******"
password = "******"

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=host_name, port=220, username=user_name, password=password)

ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put('***/issue_1.docx', '/issue_1.docx') 
ftp_client.close()
```

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sftp/paramiko_bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=host_name, port=22, username=user_name, password=password)
  File "\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 340, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 204, in _families_and_addresses
    hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hostname` parameter of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) should contain a [**hostname**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) only (or in your case an IP address) – not any kind of URL.

```
ssh_client.connect(hostname="81.149.151.143", port=220, username=..., password=...)
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883.)*

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was confused because filezilla do not connect with proper protocol ( leading sftp:// )