# SSH using Python via private keys

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, private-key

In my script, I need to do an SSH to a remote system using a private key and dump the file into its directory.

The command I am using to SSH into the system is this:

```
ssh -i private_key localhost
```

Followed by the standard input:

> Enter passphrase for key 'private_key'

I am trying to do this in a Python script, but am not sure about the way of writing a command and passing a passphrase as a parameter so that the whole sequence can be automated.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this via a library (Paramiko `SSHClient`) or a code snippet would be highly really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) can handle public key authentication with a simple call:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(hostname, username=username, key_filename=key_path, password=passphrase)
```

The `password` argument is used as a passphrase, when `key_filename` is provided.

---

*Additionally, you will also have to verify the server's host key (as you must have done with `ssh` before). See [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.