# How to configure an equivalent of ssh StrictHostKeyChecking=no in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using Paramiko for sshing from Python script. My `ssh` command is listed below:

```
ssh -A -o strictHostKeyChecking=no <hostname>
```

I need same Paramiko code for Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Paramiko, an equivalent of OpenSSH `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is the default behaviour of [`MissingHostKeyPolicy`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.MissingHostKeyPolicy), which implements [`missing_host_key`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.MissingHostKeyPolicy.missing_host_key) to simply do nothing.

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.MissingHostKeyPolicy())
client.connect(hostname, ...)
```

---

*Though you should not do this (and neither `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`). You are losing a protection against [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) this way. For correct solution, see  [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Comment: Excellent answer explaining that it shouldn't be done while still trusting the reader's judgement with exactly how to do it anyway. Thanks!