# Upload new file to SFTP server using Paramiko without having to overwrite an existing file

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to upload a file via SFTP to my server. But instead of just uploading it, I have to explicitly tell my script what file to overwrite on the server. I don't know how to change that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/home/abdulkarim/.ssh/id_rsa")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print("connecting")
c.connect( hostname = "do-test", username = "abdulkarim", pkey = k )
print("connected")
sftp = c.open_sftp()
sftp.put('/home/abdulkarim/Skripte/data/test.txt', '/home/abdulkarim/test/test1.txt')
c.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below call, the second (`remotepath`) parameter refers to the path, where the file will be stored on the server.  There is no requirement for the remote file to actually exist. It will be created.

```
sftp.put('/home/abdulkarim/Skripte/data/test.txt', '/home/abdulkarim/test/test1.txt')
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883.)*