# Paramiko TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a str or unicode or bytearray object

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'm trying to connect to an SFTP server using Python and Paramiko, but I'm getting this error (the same error occurs when I use pysftp):

```
starting thread (client mode): 0x17ccde50L
Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2)
kex algos:[u'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'rsa-sha2-512', u'rsa-sha2-256', u'ssh-dss', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', u'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:[u'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:[u'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:[u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1'] server mac:[u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1'] client compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
Compression agreed: none
kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
Unknown exception: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a str or unicode or bytearray object
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2075, in run
     self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 64, in parse_next
     return self._parse_kexecdh_reply(m)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 129, in _parse_kexecdh_reply
     self.transport._activate_outbound()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2553, in _activate_outbound
     self.local_cipher, key_out, IV_out, self._ENCRYPT
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1934, in _get_cipher
     return cipher.encryptor()
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py", line 126, in encryptor
     self.algorithm, self.mode
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 487, in create_symmetric_encryption_ctx
     return _CipherContext(self, cipher, mode, _CipherContext._ENCRYPT)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py", line 69, in __init__
     iv_nonce = self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(mode.nonce)
 TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a str or unicode or bytearray object
```

I was able to successfully connect to the SFTP server using:

```
sftp -oPort=22 xxxxx@10.132.x.x:/home
```

So I know the server exists and is accessible.

My code in Python is simply this:

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ftp_host, username=ftp_username, password=ftp_password, timeout=None)
```

And a few dependencies..

```
asn1crypto @ file:///home/folder/app/utils/asn1crypto-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
bcrypt @ file:///home/folder/app/utils/bcrypt-3.1.6-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
cffi==1.5.2 
cryptography @ file:///home/folder/app/utils/cryptography-3.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
netmiko==2.3.2
paramiko @ file:///home/folder/app/utils/vendor/paramiko-2.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ply==3.4
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycparser==2.19 
PyNaCl @ file:///home/folder/app/utils/PyNaCl-1.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
pyOpenSSL==16.0.0
six==1.9.0
```

My question is, what does this error mean exactly and what is the best way to resolve it? I need to copy images to an SFTP, but can't quite connect.

By the way, the server I'm running the Python is stuck on 2.7 and I'm not allowed to upgrade it. Also, it doesn't have access to the internet so I can't use things like apt-get. I install things by dragging and dropping zipped folders or .whl files. I just a matter of finding the correct combination of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

This topic suggests that you may have obsolete dependencies:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1027

[The solution by @bieli](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1027#issuecomment-374145838) seems to help many of those who face the problem:

```
sudo pip uninstall cryptography -y && sudo apt-get purge python3-cryptography && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo pip3 install --upgrade cryptography
```

---

*If you cannot upgrade your dependencies, you can try using a different KEX. But in general, this may be dead end.*

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample below, you  may see absolute paths to a few of the dependencies because I'm running the Python script on a remote server without internet. Therefore, .whl files had to be copied from my PC to the remote server. Of these dependencies, "**cffi**" was upgraded to version 1.11.2 and eventually resolved the issue.

If you find yourself having similar issue, try to find the best mixture of dependencies like so:

```
asn1crypto @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/asn1crypto-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
bcrypt @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/bcrypt-3.1.6-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
cffi @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/vendor/cffi-1.11.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
chrome-gnome-shell==0.0.0
cryptography @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/vendor/cryptography-2.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
cupshelpers==1.0
ecdsa==0.6
enum34 @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/vendor/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
idna==2.0
ipaddress==1.0.14
isc==2.0
netmiko==2.3.2
paramiko @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/vendor/paramiko-2.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ply==3.4
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycparser==2.19
pycryptodome @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/vendor/pycryptodome-3.6.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
pycups==1.9.66
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.20.1
PyNaCl @ file:///home/badge_bridge/utils/PyNaCl-1.3.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
pyOpenSSL==16.0.0
pysftp==0.2.9
pysmbc==1.0.13
requests==2.11.1
six==1.13.0
```