# Paramiko stdout.readlines() is too slow

Tags: python, curl, ssh, paramiko

I am using Paramiko in my Python and Django code to execute command. Here is my code:

```
client = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(<host>, username=<username>, password=<password>)
            
stdin, stdout, stderr =
    client.exec_command("curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions -T image.jpg")
lines = stdout.readlines()
```

The execution time of `stdout.readlines()` is 0.59s for each command. This is not acceptable time for my close-to-real time system. Could anyone give any suggestion to make reading process faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SSHClient.exec_command` only starts the command. It does not wait for the command to complete. That's what `readlines` does. So the `readlines` takes as long as the command does.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.