# How to use Paramiko with host definition in ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

For my SSH connections, I use this `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gwhost
Hostname gw.hostname.com
User user
IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/priv_key
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%h-%p-%r.sock
ControlPersist 120

Host *.my-example.com
User user
IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/priv_key
StrictHostKeyChecking no
ProxyCommand ssh -q 'gwhost' -W %h:22
```

From the terminal I can connect to the host like this:

```
ssh one.my-example.com
```

I want to execute some commands on a remote host using Paramiko.
I tried to do it like this:

```
host = 'one.my-example.com'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
user_config_file = os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/config")
config = SSHConfig.from_path(user_config_file)

ssh.connect(hostname=host)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

After starting I got this error

```
in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

So how can I use `~/.ssh/config` or maybe I shouldn't `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paramiko has only [very limited support for OpenSSH `ssh_config` configuration file](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/config.html).

It definitely won't use `ssh_config` automatically, the way OpenSSH `ssh` does.

You would have to instantiate `SSHConfig` class using [`SSHConfig.from_path`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/config.html#paramiko.config.SSHConfig.from_path). And then use [`SSHConfig.lookup`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/config.html#paramiko.config.SSHConfig.lookup) to lookup configuration for your hostname. And then use the returned dictionary to feed the arguments of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.