# Execute local script on remote server using non-default shell with Python Paramiko

Tags: python, bash, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to run my local `bash` script on remote server without copying it into remote server. It is as simple as following for test purpose. There are more than a few servers where it runs perfectly, but in some server running `tcsh`, there is an issue. How do I invoke `bash`, if following does not work. Below is dummy `test.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=test
echo $a
echo $SHELL
```

I am using Python Paramiko `exec_command` for remote execution as following:

```py
my_script = open("test.sh").read()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(my_script, timeout=15)
print(stdout.read().decode())
err = stderr.read().decode()
if err:
    print(err)
```

Given, that connection works and same script works for other servers with `bash` default shell.

This is the output that i get:

```
/bin/tcsh

printing from errors
a=test: Command not found.
a: Undefined variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#!/bin/bash` is a comment. Sending it to a remote shell as a command has no effect.

You have to execute `/bin/bash` on the server and send your script to it:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/bin/bash", timeout=15)
stdin.write(my_script)
```

Also, you have to `exit` the shell at the end of your script, otherwise it will never end.

Related question:
[Pass arguments to a bash script stored locally and needs to be executed on a remote machine using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64931383/850848)

Comment: thanks it worked... Also newline seemed important.