# Transfer only contents of directory using SCPClient Python

Tags: python, paramiko, scp

I am trying to move the contents from source directory `C:\report` to the remote directory `remote_server_path/Test`. Below is the code that I am trying with. Instead of just moving the contents of `C:\report`, it moves along the folder as such to the remote location. Any recommendations on how this could not be done?

```
import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient
import os

# create variables
host = "host"
username = "uname"
password = "password"

# Move files from network drive to marketing server
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=username, password=password)
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
scp.put('C:\\report', recursive=True, remote_path='remote_server_path/Test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `C:\report\*` to select *the files within the folder*.

```
scp.put('C:\\report\\*', recursive=True, remote_path='remote_server_path/Test/')
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Comment: Did this help??