# TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None in Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I am trying to make a simple SSH client, but i get this error when I try to connect:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from ipaddress import ip_address
from stdiomask import getpass

ssh = SSHClient()
try:
    server = ip_address(input("Enter IP of server: "))
except ValueError:
    print("This isn't an IP address...")
except:
    print("Enter something...")
else:
    username = input("Enter the username: ")
    password = getpass("Enter the password: ")
    ssh.connect(server, port=22, username=username, password=password)
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(input(username + "@" + server + ": "))
```

I have no idea why this isn't working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_address) for `ip_address`:

> Return an IPv4Address or IPv6Address object

`ssh.connect` is expecting the server address to be a string. You need to pass it `str(server)` or `server.exploded` as per [the `ipaddress` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.exploded).

Comment: Now I get this:
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server '185.132.36.67' not found in known_hosts

Comment: @Kemp Or just pass directly the result of `input` to the `SSHClient.connect`, instead of unnecessarily routing it via `ip_address`.

Comment: @itsmii This is not a chat. If you have a different problem, ask a new question. Though this has been asked zillion times already. Google before you ask.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883

Comment: I need to verify that the user-inputted IP is an IP.