# I want to list all the files that are in my sftp server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I want to list all the files in my server. But it returns empty like this []. What can I do? And what is wrong with my code? I am using a module called paramiko.

```
command = "ls"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing to do with SFTP. You are executing `ls` command in *remote shell*.

To list files using SFTP, use [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr):

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
for entry in sftp.listdir_attr():
    print(entry.filename)
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.