# Python os.mkdir still creates folders locally even after connecting to SSH server using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

The principle of the script is that it should connect from one virtual machine to another via an SSH connection and generate a certain number of folders.
The script runs, but when executed, generates folders on the host machine.

```
import os
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
from sys import argv
 
address = argv[1]
port = int(argv[2])
name = argv[3]
path = argv[4]
prefix = argv[5]
counts = int(argv[6])
mode = int(argv[7])
 
def generateFolders(path, prefix, counts, mode):
   for i in range(1, counts+1):
       folderName = prefix + str(i)
       pth = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), path, folderName)
       os.mkdir(pth, mode)
 
 
command = generateFolders(path, prefix, counts, mode)
 
print(address)
client1 = SSHClient()
client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client1.connect(address, username=name, password='1')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command(command)
 
print(stdout.read())
 
client1.close()
```

The command in the terminal

[image: screenshot]

But without a script, I can connect to another virtual machine
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18066854/jane), its making dirs on your local box because that is where the python script is running.

I suggest you look at this [question and answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8612/programmatically-creating-a-remote-directory-using-ssh/8614)

In that QandA, they show how to use ssh on the local box to execute commands on a remote box.  You could use your existing code as the code which is run on the remote box using the above as your guide.

Specifically this  [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8613/148343)

Answer (score 0):

The `os.mkdir` creates folders on the local machine. It won't magically start working on a remote machine only because you have previous opened SSH connection to that machine (and you actually even did not, as you open it only after calling `os.mkdir`).

To create a folder on a remote machine via Paramiko module, use [`SFTPClient.mkdir`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.mkdir).

```py
sftp = client1.open_sftp()

for i in range(1, counts+1):
    folderName = prefix + str(i)
    pth = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), path, folderName)
    sftp.mkdir(pth, mode)
```

*Though you should not use `os.path` on SFTP paths as your code will break, if run on Windows and other platforms, that does not use `/` as a path separator. And `os.path.expanduser` will of course expand `~` to local user home. I do not think you want that.*

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` on its own – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.