# Download file from SFTP server in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am using Python Paramiko to retrieve/search file from an SFTP server. I get all file in the directory.

What I need is specific file from that directory. How do I get it?

Answer (score 5):

Use Paramiko [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) to download a single file:

```
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
    with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
        sftp.get("/remote/path/file.txt", "/local/path/file.txt")
```

You will also have to [deal with the server's host key verification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create an ssh client, then execute an `ls` with piped `grep` to find your file. such as `ls /srv/ftp | grep '^FTP_'` to find files in the `/srv/ftp` directory and start with `FTP`. Then open an sftp connection and execute the `get` command to bring the files over.

EDIT: Martin below mentioned that there is a better way to get the directory contents using SFTPClient.listdir() - I have revised to that method. More info in the docs: https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html

Putting all that together looks like

```py
import paramiko

host = ''
port = 22
username = ''
password = ''

with paramiko.SSHClient() as client:
    client.connect(host, port, username, password)  
    with client.open_sftp() as sftp:
        files = sftp.listdir('/srv/ftp')
        for i, file in enumerate(files):
            if file and file.startswith('FTP'):
                sftp.get(f'/srv/ftp/{file}', f'~/ftp/{file}')
                print(f'Moved {file}')
```

This code is untested but should work. Hope that's clear.

Comment: To list files on SFTP server, use `SFTPClient.listdir(_attr)` . Do not use shell commands!

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl - you're right, that is a better way to get the directory contents. chdir, listdir, and listdir_attr are all relevant methods to the stated objective. The docs have more info for anyone else wondering: https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html

Comment: Why `for i, file in enumerate(files):`? You never use the `i`. Why not simple `for file in files`? Why `if file`?

Comment: Because it is a snippet from other code, not intended to be used directly. You're welcome to edit it to your styling preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer in case you need a kind of `find` using a SFTP connection, not knowing the exact path and name of the file. If it is not what you were looking for, I am sorry.

I made a library named [sftputil](https://pypi.org/project/sftputil/), based on [paramiko](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/), which implements advanced functionalities such as `glob`. To find a specific file and download it, you can do it this way :

```py
from sftputil import SFTP

sftp = SFTP("hostname", "username", password="password")

# Here we look for a file with a name starting with `foo`
found_files = sftp.glob("directory/foo*")

# Here we look for the file `bar` in any subdirectory
found_files = sftp.glob("directory/*/bar")

# But you can use other patterns of course.

# And now the files can be downloaded
for f in found_files:
    sftp.get(f, "my/local/path")
```

If you don’t know `glob`, you should read the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob), as this implementation works the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Use Paramiko SFTPClient.get to download a single file:

First  install : `pip install paramiko` from [this link](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/).

```
import paramiko
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
    with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
        sftp.get("/remote/path/file.txt", "/local/path/file.txt")
```

NOTE:  `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())` is important for add ssh key (just in case if security is not important( like develop mode) use `AutoAddPolicy` ).

Comment: Please do not ever recommend anyone to use `AutoAddPolicy` this way. That's a security flaw. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).