# Download files from SFTP server to specific local directory using Python pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I'm attempting to download a set of files from an SFTP server. I can download the files successfully, but now I want to change the script so that as the files download, they go to a specified directory on my local server.

I attempted doing this with the `sftp.getfo()` command, but am getting an error:

> getfo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fl'

```
#SET LOCAL DIRECTORY
directory1 = r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\test sftp'

#CONNECT TO SFTP
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host = hostname, username = usereu, password = passeu, cnopts = cnopts)
print("Connection successfully established ... ")

#DOWNLOAD ALL FILES IN FOLDER
files = sftp.listdir()
for file in files:
   sftp.getfo(remotepath = file, fl = directory1)
   print(file,' downloaded successfully ')
```

Am I using the right command here or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download a file to local path, use [`Connection.get`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get) (not `getfo`):

```
sftp.get(remotepath=file, localpath=os.path.join(directory1, file))
```

---

Some notes:

- `remotepath` takes path to the remote file, not just filename. Your code (which passes filename only) works only because you are downloading from the home folder.
- The pysftp is dead. Do not use it. Use Paramiko. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)

  For an example, see [Download file from SFTP server in Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72556812/850848)
- Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848).