# How to add '\n" to a variable value to submit it as an input of remote process via Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, cisco, getpass

I am working with Paramiko on Linux, I would like to know if I can send a variable to shell. I want to enter to "enable mode" of a Cisco router. But I don't want to hard-code the password in the script. I am using `getpass`, but when I run the script it fails in the `enable` command. I get *"bad secrets"*. I know that happens for wrong password. I know shell had to add `\n` in the end of the command. But how I can add to a variable?

```
#!/bin/python3
import paramiko
import time
import getpass

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

password = getpass.getpass('Enter password: ')
router = {'hostname': '192.168.142.132', 'port': '22', 'username':'user', 'password': password}

print(f"Connecting to {router['hostname']} ")
ssh_client.connect(**router, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
shell = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
shell.send('enable\n')
passwordE = getpass.getpass('Enter the enable password:')
shell.send('passwordE')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` operator.

```
shell.send(passwordE + '\n')
```

Or you can simply call `send` twice:

```
shell.send(passwordE)
shell.send('\n')
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.