# Downloading files from WinSCP using Python script

Tags: python, putty, python-module, winscp, winscp-net

How to download multiple files from different location folders from WinSCP server to the local folder using python script?

Is there any python module available which I can import and use that to download the files.

Note: I am using putty to log in to WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like *"WinSCP server"*. *WinSCP* is a *client* that can connect using various protocols to a remote file server. How you implement the same in Python depends on actual protocol you use with WinSCP. Based on your reference to *"PuTTY"*, I assume you use SSH/SFTP.

For an SFTP download, use [Paramiko Python library](https://www.paramiko.org/) with its [`SFTPClient.get`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) method. An example of a download of a single file:

```
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
    with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
        sftp.get("/remote/path/file.txt", "/local/path/file.txt")
```

You will also have to [deal with the server's host key verification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).