# connect to a remote system with a subprocess call without entering a password

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to access a remote machine to execute remote a Python script (`remote_test.py`).

I changed the SSH configuration so that if I enter `ssh user@ip` from host terminal it connects to remote system without asking for password.

When I run a Python script on the host machine to execute `remote_test.py` by using SSH in a subprocess call like this:

```
P = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "ssh",
        "user@some_ip",
        "sudo",
        "python",
        "/home/path/remote_test.py",
    ],
    shell=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

It requires me to enter a password.

How can I access the remote machine without needing to enter a password?

Environment:

- Python version 2.7
- Host and Remote systems are both using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Some formatting changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Popen` to run the program `ssh`, but rather use a library like the excellent `paramiko` to run ssh commands.  It has a documented API for connecting using public keys, which is discussed here: [How to ssh connect through python Paramiko with public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382847/how-to-ssh-connect-through-python-paramiko-with-public-key)

Then you'll be able to do something like this:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.connect('some_ip', username='user', key_filename='keyfile')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo python /home/path/remote_test.py')
```