# Passwordless SSH connection with Paramiko fails where as with SSH works

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I intend to create a use passwordless connection using SSH Keys between a client and a server.

Using paramiko, I end up in a *AuthenticationException*. Using standard SSH via Popen, I can connect without problems

For Paramiko I use the following code:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(ssh_server, username=ssh_user)
```

For the same situation, I am able to use SSH:

```
cmd = 'ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o ForwardX11=no {}@{} echo 0 > /dev/null'.format(ssh_user, ssh_server)
process = subprocess.Popen(md, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
process.communicate()
```

I am using Python 3.4.6 and Paramiko 2.4.1.

Some more details:

- I am able to establish a connection with Paramiko on a different client
- On this specific client, the user for ssh impersonation is not the same as the user who starts the call.

**Paramiko Debug Output**

```
2018-07-11 20:55:54,025 20730 DEBUG: putting paramiko output to console
2018-07-11 20:55:54,112 20730 DEBUG: starting thread (client mode): 0x4ca07320
2018-07-11 20:55:54,112 20730 DEBUG: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.4.1
2018-07-11 20:55:54,112 20730 DEBUG: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
2018-07-11 20:55:54,112 20730 INFO: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2)
2018-07-11 20:55:54,115 20730 DEBUG: kex algos:['curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] server mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
2018-07-11 20:55:54,115 20730 DEBUG: Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
2018-07-11 20:55:54,115 20730 DEBUG: HostKey agreed: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
2018-07-11 20:55:54,115 20730 DEBUG: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
2018-07-11 20:55:54,115 20730 DEBUG: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
2018-07-11 20:55:54,116 20730 DEBUG: Compression agreed: none
2018-07-11 20:55:54,123 20730 DEBUG: kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
2018-07-11 20:55:54,124 20730 DEBUG: Switch to new keys ...
Exception: No authentication methods available
```

**SSH DEBUG: (using ssh -v ssh_user AT ssh_server)**

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/pid1083/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/pid1083/.ssh/config line 17: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <ssh_server> port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<logged_in_username>/.ssh/id_rsa_c2c type 1
debug1: identity file /home/<logged_in_username>/.ssh/id_rsa_c2c-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 21:1b:bb:32:4c:69:f3:eb:91:79:e7:ca:d4:30:ff:70
debug1: Host '<ssh_server>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<logged_in_username>/.ssh/known_hosts:519
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/<logged_in_user>/.ssh/id_rsa_c2c
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <IP_of_server>:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_COLLATE = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_DK.utf8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ssh` connection works, because it uses a private key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa_c2c` (as configured in `ssh_config`). The `.ssh` folder and `ssh_config` file serve as a configuration for OpenSSH toolset (`ssh` in this case). You cannot expect that other SSH clients/libraries will use OpenSSH configuration files. They won't, in general.

If you want to use public key authentication with Paramiko, use `key_filename` argument of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect).
See also [How to ssh connect through Python Paramiko with ppk public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8382847/850848).

Though Paramiko, in particular, would use a key file, if it had a common name like `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, etc. See [Force password authentication (ignore keys in .ssh folder) in Paramiko in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52632693/850848) for exactly opposite problem.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy`, unless you do not care about security. You are losing a protection against MITM attacks this way.

For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Comment: Thank you, your reasoning is clear and makes sense. I will try it out and if it works, mark it as resolved.