# Force password authentication (ignore keys in .ssh folder) in Paramiko in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to write a small Python program to check whether an SSH server allows a password authentication. Here is the current plan:

```
import base64
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('ssh.example.com', username='strongbad', password='thecheat')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
client.close()
```

The idea is to grep the output or to later put a `try` `catch` block around the `connect` statement.

My problem however is that some of the systems that I run the program on have access via a RSA key that is stored under `~/.ssh`. And in these cases, the connect will simply succeed (which I want to avoid).

So, here is the question: Does anybody know any way to force Paramiko (or another SSH client) to use passwords?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) method has `look_for_keys` argument. Set it to `False`:

```
client.connect(
    'ssh.example.com', username='strongbad', password='thecheat',
    look_for_keys=False)
```

Similarly you may want to set `allow_agent` to `False` as well.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy`, unless you do not care about security. You are losing a protection against MITM attacks this way.

For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.