# Paramiko equivalent for OpenSSH directives PreferredAuthentications=password and PubkeyAuthentication=no

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, openssh

Can I get Paramiko code for the following `ssh` command?

```
ssh Administrator@xx.xx.xx.xx -vv -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

Need to know how to handle fields `PreferredAuthentications` and `PubkeyAuthentication` in Paramiko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent, as Paramiko has different logic than `ssh` when selecting the authentication methods. And you actually didn't tell us why are you using those directives.

If your point was to avoid using autodiscovered key files, use `allow_agent=False` and `look_for_keys=False`.

See [Force password authentication (ignore keys in .ssh folder) in Paramiko in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52632693/850848)

Comment: Thanks @Martin Prikryl..... "look_for_keys=FALSE" served my purpose.