# Paramiko SFTPClient class throws "Authentication failed", but Transport class and WinSCP work

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I have an issue using Paramiko and connecting to an SFTP server.

The connecting work fine using same credentials in WinSCP.
I am also able to use pysftp.
But I would prefer to be able to use Paramiko, which gives access to better control of timeouts (removed in the example below).

I get the following error in the last Paramiko example:

> paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

What is even more strange, the exact same code, works for my colleague.
So anyone have a clue what I should look into?

```py
import pysftp
from base64 import decodebytes
import paramiko

username = "my_username"
password = "my_secret_password"
hostname = "ftp.hostname.tld"
directory = "/protected/directory"
port = 22
keydata = b"""AAAAB...TuQ=="""
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))

# PYSFTP is working!
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add(hostname, 'ssh-rsa', key)
with pysftp.Connection(host=hostname, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    files = sftp.listdir_attr(directory)
    test = "test"

# This pure Paramiko is also working!
with paramiko.Transport((hostname,port)) as transport:
    transport.connect(
        hostkey=key,
        username=username,
        password=password
    )
    with paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport) as sftp:
        files = sftp.listdir_attr(directory)
        test = "test"

# This version where the transport is established using sshclient, does not work.
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.get_host_keys().add(hostname=hostname, keytype="ssh-rsa", key=key)
ssh_client.connect(
    hostname=hostname, 
    username=username,
    password=password,
    port=port
)
sftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()
files = sftp.listdir_attr(directory)
test = "test"
```

Paramiko log from a failed session:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x5dad0e50
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_3.1.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-srtSSHServer_11.00
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client srtSSHServer_11.00)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: diffie-hellman-group14-sha256, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha512@ssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: aes256-ctr, aes128-ctr, aes256-cbc, twofish256-cbc, aes128-cbc, twofish256-ctr, aes192-ctr, twofish192-ctr, twofish128-ctr, twofish128-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: aes256-ctr, aes128-ctr, aes256-cbc, twofish256-cbc, aes128-cbc, twofish256-ctr, aes192-ctr, twofish192-ctr, twofish128-ctr, twofish128-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: hmac-sha3-512, hmac-sha3-384, hmac-sha3-256, hmac-sha3-224, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha2-384, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-224, hmac-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: hmac-sha3-512, hmac-sha3-384, hmac-sha3-256, hmac-sha3-224, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha2-384, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-224, hmac-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: ssh-rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== End of kex handshake ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Got server p (2048 bits)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexGexSHA256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'f28c2e56806b573d7fc45b9722242e5b' in C:\Users\my-user/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Finalizing pubkey algorithm for key of type 'ssh-rsa'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Our pubkey algorithm list: ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa']
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Server did not send a server-sig-algs list; defaulting to our first preferred algo ('rsa-sha2-512')
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:NOTE: you may use the 'disabled_algorithms' SSHClient/Transport init kwarg to disable that or other algorithms if your server does not support them!
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
INFO:paramiko.transport:Disconnect (code 2): unexpected service request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SSHClient` is automatically trying the `~/.ssh/id_*` keys. You have `id_rsa` there.

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key b'f28c2e56806b573d7fc45b9722242e5b' in C:\Users\my-user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Normally, it would do not harm, as it would fail and Paramiko will then try the password.

But recent versions of Paramiko are too strict by default about use of SHA-256 signatures:
[Paramiko authentication fails with "Agreed upon 'rsa-sha2-512' pubkey algorithm" (and "unsupported public key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512" in sshd log)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70565357/850848)

As your server does not support it, Paramiko fails when trying the key. And the password authentication never happens.

Use `look_for_keys=False` to ignore the keys in `~/.ssh`. See:
[Force password authentication (ignore keys in .ssh folder) in Paramiko in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52632693/850848)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this setting to the connect() call:

look_for_keys=False,

Makes the above code work.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @martin-prikryl