# Robot Framework - SSH Library - Login With Public Key

Tags: ssh, robotframework, paramiko, ssh-keys, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am trying to create a SSH connection with the Private Key from **Robot Framework with SSH library** to the machine which is hosted on AWS cloud. The keyword being used is - **Login With Public Key**.
Below is the code which is currently written in Eclipse with Red editor

```
*** Variables ***
${hostname}    <hostname>
${username}    <username>


*** Test Cases ***
ConnectionToJump
    Set Log Level    DEBUG
    Enable Ssh Logging    logfile.txt
    Log    Starting the connection to jump server
    ${connectionIndex}    Open Connection    ${hostname}    port=22
    ${output}    Login With Public Key    ${username}    C:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa.ppk
    Log    ${output}
```

But unfortunately, this is throwing me error in the Eclipse console which looks like

```
Starting test: Demo-Telemetry.TestCases.ConnectToJumpServer.ConnectionToJump
20210616 12:52:54.448 : INFO : Log level changed from INFO to DEBUG.
20210616 12:52:54.449 : INFO : SSH log is written to <a href="logfile.txt">file</a>.
20210616 12:52:54.449 : INFO : Starting the connection to jump server
20210616 12:52:54.450 : INFO : ${connectionIndex} = 1
20210616 12:52:54.451 : INFO : Logging into '<hostname>:22' as '<username>'.
20210616 12:52:54.643 : DEBUG : Adding ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host key for <hostname>: b'db779d1ed1b0995ec97b1cbe96c27c5f'
20210616 12:52:54.888 : FAIL : Login with public key failed for user '<username>'.
20210616 12:52:54.888 : DEBUG : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\library.py", line 1043, in login_with_public_key
    return self._login(self.current.login_with_public_key, username,
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\SSHLibrary\library.py", line 1059, in _login
    raise RuntimeError(e)
Ending test: Demo-Telemetry.TestCases.ConnectToJumpServer.ConnectionToJump
```

On checking the SSH log from the logfile.txt, the information is as follows

```
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.532] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xfdaa1340
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.533] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.558] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
INF [20210616-12:52:54.558] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.607] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:['aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha2-256'] server mac:['hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha2-256'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.607] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.607] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.607] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.608] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.608] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.642] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.642] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.643] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host key for sshhost.fftest.tst.zipbo.mop-test.comp.db.de: b'db779d1ed1b0995ec97b1cbe96c27c5f'
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.747] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.782] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication type (password) not permitted.
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.783] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Allowed methods: ['publickey']
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.815] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.857] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication type (none) not permitted.
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.857] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Allowed methods: ['publickey']
DEB [20210616-12:52:54.884] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.884] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Unknown exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'public_blob'
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.886] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.886] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2109, in run
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.886] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     handler(self.auth_handler, m)
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.886] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 289, in _parse_service_accept
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.886] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     if self.private_key.public_blob:
ERR [20210616-12:52:54.886] thr=1   paramiko.transport: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'public_blob'
```

I am able to create the connection manually with PuTTY and MobaXterm with the same key file successfully.

Can you please help me to understand what mistake i am doing or what needs to be altered to make a successful connection .

Thanks

Comment: based on robot framework SSH lib documentation 
`password is used to unlock the keyfile if needed. If the keyfile is invalid a username-password authentication will be attempted.
`

and your logfile.txt - password authentication is atempted. i would think that your key file is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot framework SSH library uses paramiko. based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382847/how-to-ssh-connect-through-python-paramiko-with-ppk-public-key) paramiko cannot parse ppk keys. You need to convert .ppk file to openssh private key format

Comment: Thank You @Jiri Janous for your suggestion. It helped me in fixing it and achieving what I was trying to do.