# Robot Framework SSHLibrary Login With Public gives error: Key Authentication type (password) not permitted

Tags: robotframework, paramiko

I'm working in a legacy Robotframework project that uses the SSHLibrary.
We changed authentication on the SSH server from username with password to public/private key.

I'm using the following keyword based on the documentation from SSHLibrary:

```
Login With Public Key   root     /home/test/.ssh/key
```

This fails, in the SSH logs I see the following:

```
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.160] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xd9528410L
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.167] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_1.18.5
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.220] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
INF [20220315-11:05:32.220] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.8)
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.227] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:[u'curve25519-sha256', u'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', u'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:[u'rsa-sha2-512', u'rsa-sha2-256', u'ssh-rsa', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', u'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:[u'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] server encrypt:[u'chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com'] client mac:[u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1'] server mac:[u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1'] client compress:[u'none'] server compress:[u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.228] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.229] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.229] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.229] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.229] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.516] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGroup14 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.517] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.519] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-rsa host key for 192.168.1.1: 6d16a4a7a06421c155735b4a89c7ba9c
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.530] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.550] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication type (password) not permitted.
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.550] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Allowed methods: [u'publickey']
DEB [20220315-11:05:32.707] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
WAR [20220315-11:05:32.708] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Oops, unhandled type 3
```

It seems to me that instead of using public key authentication it still is trying to connect with a password.

```
Robotframework = 2.8.7
Robotframework-SSHLibrary = 2.1.3
Paramiko = 1.18.5
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68001504/robot-framework-ssh-library-login-with-public-key/68002682#68002682) answer your question?

Comment: No the key is in OpenSSH format

Comment: and you are able to connect from the console without any issues?

Comment: Yes we can connect from the console

Comment: that is strange, I would still suspect the username or keyfile based on the ssh library documentation. > **"password is used to unlock the keyfile if needed. If the keyfile is invalid a username-password authentication will be attempted."**

Answer (score 1):

Your Paramiko version is pretty old, it cannot deal with new OpenSSH format keys. You should convert it to classic OpenSSH format:
`ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f /home/test/.ssh/key`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000004) for more details