# How do I use Login With Public Key from Robot Framework SSHLibrary

Tags: python, ssh, robotframework

I am attempting to set up a generic method in Robot Framework using SSHLibrary that will let me specify an IP on my network and then execute an arbitrary command using the Execute Command keyword. I want to do this using my ssh keys, as I am avoiding exposing network passwords for security reasons. I've run into the problem that the keys simply do not seem to work, and I feel like I'm missing something. Here's a snippet of the code that matters:

```
Execute Command over SSH
    [Arguments]    ${host}    ${username}    ${command}

    Enable Ssh Logging    sshlog.txt
    Open Connection    ${host}
    Login With Public Key    username=${username}    keyfile=%{HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa
```

As it stands now, execution fails at Login With Public Key with this failure message: `Login with public key failed for user 'user'`. I've investigated several avenues for an answer but all have turned up short. What I've considered thus far:

- SSH to the server in question *is* functional. I have executed this same code using the Login keyword in place of this existing one (the one requiring username and password). The result was a successful login to the expected ip with the expected user.
- My keys should be the correct format. I have seen several articles and Stack Overflow threads (in particular, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68001504/robot-framework-ssh-library-login-with-public-key)) that ran into issues with Paramiko key format. However, the issues all seemed to be resolved by ensuring the keys used were in an RSA format and executing ssh-keygen to that end. Upon inspection, I can confirm that my ssh key is in an RSA format as it begins with this line: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. I will, however, note that the key does not have a file extension while its pair has the extension `.pub`, if that means anything.
- I have tried generating fresh ssh keys in case the one I had had some issue with it. I am confident that I regenerated the keys correctly because I had to perform a new ssh-copy-id to each of the devices on the network for which I use passwordless ssh.
- I have verified that the user executing Robot Framework is indeed my own, and thus should be expected to use my ssh setup and credentials.
- I attempted to use the keyword’s look_for_keys parameter to discover my ssh key just in case my filepath was wrong somehow.
- I separately verified that the filepath to the keyfile was accurate and that look_for_keys discovered the key.
- The destination server has the public key for the user in question based on a manual check of the user's .ssh/id_rsa.pub file
- I have not attempted to involve the ssh agent in my attempts to solve this, mainly because it does not start as active when I log into the testing system from my remote desktop. (That's another thing: This is all being executed from a remote server that I am logging into from elsewhere.)
- I have double-checked the versions of the libraries on the device executing the tests. I am running on a CentOS OS and I have openssh v7.4, python v3.7.3, paramiko v2.6.0, robotframework v5.0, scp v 0.13.2, and sshlibrary v3.8. I believe these libraries are sufficiently updated to be able to execute SSHLibrary as expected.
- As a last-ditch effort, I tried referencing the config file I use for my ssh aliases using the read_config parameter. It gave the same result, although I'm surprised the connect statement was able to work and I'm curious as to why. [obligatory "my code works and I don't know why" joke]

The following is the output sent to sshlog.txt. The results are consistent across different attempts at execution. The output presented is at the INFO level. If truly necessary, I can modify to include debug info upon request:

```
# all lines are prepended with [LogLv] [datetime] [thread#] paramiko.transport:
Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.0)
Authentication (publickey) failed.
Authentication (password) failed.
Unknown exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'public_blob'
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2109, in run
     handler(self.auth_handler, m)
   File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 289, in _parse_service_accept
     if self.private_key.public_blob:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'public_blob'
```

I suppose, at the end of the day, my ultimate question is: **how am I *intended* to set up my ssh keys and the network to support the use of ssh keys in Robot Framework?** If there’s something I’m not understanding here, an explanation or a resource would be greatly appreciated as my research has not yielded much of use and, as you can imagine, I’ve exhausted any of the paths to a solution that I can imagine.

Comment: did you try using ssh directly in the shell with the given private key and user combo ? you mentioned 7.2 sshd - it is rather old and it might not support the generated key if you have done it with newer ssh since, rsa sha1 signature was deprecated ..

Comment: and 99% the time, if the machine you  are connnecting *TO* doesnt have right permissions of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  -key based auth does not work.

Comment: And one question:  did you create the key with or without passphrase ?

Comment: Yes, I have been able to log into the server in the terminal using ssh with the key and user combo. I am also fairly confident that the target system has the keys, though I am not sure how to check if key-based authorization would work in this context. What command can I use to check? The key was created without a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changed my private key file format to PEM and it fixed.

a PEM key file starts with

—–BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY—–

And a RFC4716 starts with:

—–BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY—–

so I run `:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -p -f id_rsa -m PEM`, then could connect via RSA key.