# ssh with keys and without passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I want to copy directories with scp from server A to a remote server B. As i want to do this with a script I generated a private and a public key for the server, which work fine with winScp.

but when i try to copy with shell/skript

```
scp -i <DIR>/key.ppk $tmpDirA/*.war $username@$server:$TmpDirB
```

Im getting asked for the passphrase

```
Enter passphrase for key '<DIR>/key.ppk'
```

even the passphrase was left empty when generating the keys.

both server(openSuse) have openSsh, protocol 2. and the keys are rsa-keys

This keys are not generated with the server A. Does it matter?

I cant see what point im missing. So thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to use a PUTTY private key?  Openssh does not support putty private key files, but [PUTTYgen can export to a format openssh understands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use).

Comment: so silly.. Yeah, that was the point. I knew that i had to generate the key.. no idea when I forgot that again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ssh chooses the right key when copying?

Create a config file in ~/.ssh and define different hosts there, this ensures that ssh chooses the correct key.

[Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

Comment: do you mean the public key? He asks for the phrase of the private-key "Enter passphrase for key '<DIR>/key.ppk'", so ssh chooses the right private-key.