# scp copy directory to another server with private key auth

Tags: linux, ssh, copy, file-transfer, scp

is there something wrong with this scp command ?

```
scp -C -i ./remoteServerKey.ppk -r /var/www/* root@192.168.0.15:/var/www
```

I use the same .ppk as in putty and enter the same passphrase, but it asks me 3 times and than says connection denied. I thought I used it before and it worked, but it isn´t atm.
If it is wrong, how should I do it ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I'm searching for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putty doesn't use openssh key files - there is a utility in putty suite to convert them.

edit: it is called [puttygen](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen)

Comment: I think this is the issue, I´m gonna test it as soon as I´m home.

Answer (score 57):

or you can also do ( for **pem** file )

```
 scp -r -i file.pem user@192.10.10.10:/home/backup /home/user/Desktop/
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer as per its subtleness & to the pointness.

Comment: if you have a ppk file, convert to pem first using: https://tecadmin.net/convert-ppk-to-pem-using-command/

Answer (score 35):

Covert .ppk to id_rsa using tool PuttyGen, (http://mydailyfindingsit.blogspot.in/2015/08/create-keys-for-your-linux-machine.html) and

```
scp -C -i ./id_rsa -r /var/www/* root@192.168.0.15:/var/www
```

it should work !

Comment: Converting to openssh key from ppk and then using your command asked me for passphrase. Any idea why? Cause of that I'm unable to connect and copy.

Comment: http://thanosk.net/content/conver-putty-ppk-key-ssh-key This link created a key that worked for me without any issue. Thanks for the command though.

Answer (score 2):

The command looks quite fine. Could you try to run -v (verbose mode) and then we can figure out what it is wrong on the authentication?

Also as mention in the other answer, maybe could be this issue - that you need to convert the keys (answered already here): [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use) OR http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen (depending what you need)